# фон текста в tinyMCE Advanced (Wordpress)

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, tinymce

В wordpress поставлен плагин - tinyMCE Advanced. При копировании из *.doc любой текст с фоном - фон не распознается в tinyMCE. Цвет текста без проблем, фон текста - никак.

При скачивании и установке tinyMCE с офф сайта и развертывании в каком нибудь *.html - работает без проблем, в демо, предоставленном от разработчиков, тоже.

На сколько понял - это базовый функционал, т.е. без прагинов tinyMCE уже может распознавать фон текста.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/

Как пофиксить, куда копать?

Comment: Видимо tinyMCE wordpress'a вырезает часть html кода.

Comment: Наверно, спасибо за совет (мысль).